# Stop/kill Bigquery in console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, automation

We have an use case regrading the big query.

We have one dashboard to identify long running query or query which scanned more data and need to optimize.
Suppose any user writing a query in bigQuery Cloud Console, and it showing it will scan 300 GB data, so any method to stop that user before running the query in realtime.

I try with cloud function and pub/sub, but problem is, I can not figure it out, which bigQuery event will trigger that function

Answer (score 0):

You can set up query quotas to limit the amount of data a user can scan in a single query, which can help prevent long-running or resource-intensive queries from being executed.

For that, you can use the BigQuery API or the Cloud Console and this is how to do it using the Cloud Console:

- Open the BigQuery web UI in the Cloud Console.
- Click on the "Quotas" tab.
- Under "Query quota," click "Edit quota."
- In the "Request limit" field, enter the maximum amount of data that a user can scan in a single query.
- In the "Period" field, specify the time period over which the quota applies (e.g., "1 day") and then save.

A source: [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)

Comment: Thank You so much Ledian for the answer, Actually we have quota in place for the service accounts, but when individual users are querying the data, that time the problem arise. As user query requirement is not fixed, we could not determined for the individual user quota. Is there any other alternative?